# Displaying table-row border on hover

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

I work with a div table, but when I set **hover** on row, it does not work, the header / **.thead** is all right, but on the **.tbody** it does not work, the hover only displays **left border**, **right border**, and **bottom border** , did I forget something? How to solve it? This is my code:

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0 5px;
}

.divTable .tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTable .thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTable .td,
.th {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.divTable .thead {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTable .tfoot {
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTable .tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.divTable {
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: default;
  width: 100%;
}

.divTable .th,
.divTable .td {
  padding: 4px 6px;
}

.divTable .tr {
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 26px;
}

.divTable .tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(162, 216, 242, 0.14);
  border: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
  height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="thead">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="th">Filename</div>
      <div class="th">Type</div>
      <div class="th">Size</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tbody">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Why Cannot Work.jpg</div>
      <div class="td">Image</div>
      <div class="td">12.1 KB</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Lorem Ipsum.jpg</div>
      <div class="td">Image</div>
      <div class="td">12.1 KB</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Dolor Sir Amet.jpg</div>
      <div class="td">Image</div>
      <div class="td">12.1 KB</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's how `border-collapse` works because the bottom border of upper cell is collapsed into the top border of the bottom cell.

One of the ways of working around this would be to specify borders on the `.td` elements. So you would give top and bottom borders to all `.td` cells, and left and right borders respectively to the `:first-child` and `:last-child` respectively. This would effectively achieve what you want.

```
.divTable .tr:hover .td {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
}

.divTable .tr:hover .td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
}

.divTable .tr:hover .td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
}
```

Here's a snippet showing how that would look:

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0 5px;
}

.divTable .tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTable .thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTable .td,
.th {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.divTable .thead {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTable .tfoot {
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTable .tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.divTable {
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: default;
  width: 100%;
}

.divTable .th,
.divTable .td {
  padding: 4px 6px;
}

.divTable .tr {
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 26px;
}

.divTable .tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(162, 216, 242, 0.14);
  border: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
  height: 26px;
}

.divTable .tr:hover .td {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
}

.divTable .tr:hover .td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
}
.divTable .tr:hover .td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="thead">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="th">Filename</div>
      <div class="th">Type</div>
      <div class="th">Size</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tbody">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Why Cannot Work.jpg</div>
      <div class="td">Image</div>
      <div class="td">12.1 KB</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Lorem Ipsum.jpg</div>
      <div class="td">Image</div>
      <div class="td">12.1 KB</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Dolor Sir Amet.jpg</div>
      <div class="td">Image</div>
      <div class="td">12.1 KB</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing following will solve your problem:

```
.divTable .tr {
 border: 1px solid white;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Nisarg's method works, but its much simpler to remove and add just these two lines from your original code.
Remove {border: 1px solid white;} from .divTable .tr

and the reason you added this was probably so the cells dont move around when you hover them. Just add {border: 1px solid transparent;} to .divTable

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.divTable .tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTable .thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTable .td,
.th {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.divTable .thead {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTable .tfoot {
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTable .tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.divTable {
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: default;
  width: 100%;
}

.divTable .th,
.divTable .td {
  padding: 4px 6px;
}

.divTable .tr {
  height: 26px;
}

.divTable .tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(162, 216, 242, 0.14);
  border: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(124, 204, 243, 0.58);
  height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="thead">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="th">Filename</div>
      <div class="th">Type</div>
      <div class="th">Size</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tbody">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Why Cannot Work.jpg</div>
      <div class="td">Image</div>
      <div class="td">12.1 KB</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Lorem Ipsum.jpg</div>
      <div class="td">Image</div>
      <div class="td">12.1 KB</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Dolor Sir Amet.jpg</div>
      <div class="td">Image</div>
      <div class="td">12.1 KB</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```